# How to call MongoDB periodically Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

How can I call this code/function every X seconds/minutes. I think i could use setInterval, eg: `setInterval('function()', 5000);`, but i don't know how to use it in this case

```
list = [];
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("mydb");
  dbo
    .collection("collection")
    .find({ valx: "false" }, { projection: { id: 0 } })
    .toArray(function (err, result) {
      for (i in result) {
        list.push(result[i]);
      }
      console.log("u called bd");
      db.close();
    });
});
//setInterval('how to call mongoclient.connect()', 5000);
```

This code works!, but i would like to call it every X seconds/minutes. Thank you in advance guys ♥

Comment: Wrap it in a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
let list = [];
setInterval(() => {
  MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    let dbo = db.db("mydb");
    dbo
      .collection("collection")
      .find({ valx: "false" }, { projection: { id: 0 } })
      .toArray(function (err, result) {
        for (i in result) {
          list.push(result[i]);
        }
        console.log("u called bd");
        db.close();
      });
  });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, and thank you for your time. God bless u ♥